# Total numbers in the given range having 2 divisors

Tags: c++

We have given the number of iterations upto which the number of ranges should be taken as input. Like if the number of iterations(n)=2, we have to input 2 ranges. And then for each range we have to count and print the total number of integers which have exactly two divisors. Sample input/output format is given below the code.

This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    long long int n, a, b, count=0, j, k, flag=1, ans=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cin>>a>>b;
        for(j=a;j<=b;j++){
            if(j==1){
                continue;
            }
            else if(j==2){
                count++;
            }
            else{
                for(k=1;k<=j;k++){
                    if(j%k==0){
                        flag=0;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==1){
                    ans++;
                }
            }
            if(ans==2){
                count++;
            }
        }
        cout<<count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input Format
The first line contains N , no of test cases. The next N lines contain two integers a and b denoting the range of country numbers.

Output Format
Output contains N lines each containing an answer for the test case.

```
Sample Input 
2 
1 10 
11 20

Sample Output 
4 
4

My output 
1 
1
```

Comment: What ıs your question. Please elaborate

Comment: You probably want `flag = 1;` (or better `bool flag = true;`) before `for(k=1;k<=j;k++)`. There may be other issues - I don't really understand the question - so please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: When a number only has 2 divisors (except 1 and the number itself), there's something special you can observe about this numbers. Please look at the 1-10 range and 11-20 range, what can you generalize about these numbers?